# How to configure the HP MSA 1040 storage for direct connection to the server

Tags: networking, router, windows-server-2016, iscsi

I am following the [tutorial](http://www.georgealmeida.com/2015/03/configure-iscsi-on-windows-server-2012-r2/) to configure my HP MSA 1040 storage device. My setup is as follows:

**Setup**:

Fibre Channel(iSCSI) wires connected from the A1 to the server.

Fibre Channel(iSCSI) wires connected from the B1 to the server.

Network wire connected from MSA controller A to the router(DHCP) for the management through ssh, or http. IP address is 192.168.1.2

Network wire connected from MSA controller B to the router(DHCP) for the management through ssh, or http. IP address is 192.168.1.3

I am not able to follow in the tutorial what does he mean when he says assign IP addresses to A1 port and B1 port. How can i assign the IP address since they do not show in my router because they are not directly connected to the router and neither will be. Even if i assign IP address of the same network, Windows server does not find it through the iSCSI initiator. How should i resolve this problem in order to connect my storage device to the server. My hp MSA device shows that port A1 and B1 iSCSI ports are connected and up but still not able to see why i cannot see the disks on the windows server 2016?

Comment: You'll want to ask this question on serverfault.com, which is dedicated to professional systems administration.  This site is about programming topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://www.georgealmeida.com/2015/03/configure-iscsi-on-windows-server-2012-r2/) was showing that the HP MSA 1040 was connected through the network switches, but in my case i had connected them directly so i had to assign them private IP addresses. I assigned my A1 with 192.168.0.1 and B1 with 192.168.0.2 and similarly assigned my NIC cards on server with 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.0.4.

Next, i setup the iSCSI using the Target portals in the iSCSI initiator by mentioning the ip addresses of both the controllers and other settings as default and then the device was shown as connected. This [link](https://www.oxhow.com/connect-two-windows-7-computers-on-lan-using-ethernet-cable/) helped in understanding how to assign private ip addressing to the HP MSA SAN devices.